# Tab Order Tool in VS - Can't See Controls Through Labels

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017

When using the "View" > "Tab Order" function, the labels that appear make it so that I can't see the underlying controls to click on them.

I looked in the application options but didn't see any way to turn these labels off.

Any ideas for how to get around this would be very much appreciated.[image]

Comment: You have burnt my eyes.

Comment: I probably should have put a warning label in the title

Comment: Do you need the labels?  Drawing the text in the container's Paint event is a good way to not use labels.  Also, those GroupBoxes look like they could be converted to UserControls.

Comment: Dang, 2 years later and no answer for this, I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Select View->Tab Order again or on the Layout toolbar look for the Tab Order icon:

[image: Tab Order Icon on the Layout Toolbar]

You can also just click on the labels themselves to change the tab order.

Comment: That's not what the question is about.  The controls that the op wants to set the TabIndex on using this tool is hidden by all the labels.

Comment: The question states "I looked in the application options but didn't see any way to turn these labels off.". If you can't see the labels how would you know what the tab order was?

Comment: The OP isn't trying to set the TabOrder of the labels.

Comment: I know that! The labels show the tab order of the controls underneath them! When you click a label it changes the tab order of the control not the label.

Comment: Correct, I'm just wanting to see my controls (below the blue boxes added by the "Tab Order" tool) so that I can click on them...

Comment: If the tab order labels are blocking other tab order labels you'll either need to use the tab order property setter in the Properties window or start breaking your UI down into individual user controls. Seems that the tab order tool was never designed for the amount of nesting you've got going on.

Comment: To make things a little easier you could open the Document Outline window. That'll show you your control hierarchy. From there you can go through each one and set the Tab Index in the properties window.